# Cannot build EAS Project, Invalid regular expression: Range out of order in character class

Tags: regex, react-native, expo, eas, react-native-svg

I encountered an error while building my Expo application with EAS. I used the following command:
`eas build -p android --profile preview`
The error message is as follows:

```
Loaded "env" configuration for the "preview" profile: no environment variables specified. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/
✔ Using remote Android credentials (Expo server)
✔ Using Keystore from configuration: Build Credentials RG9Js_N0gy (default)

Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/eas-build-archive
Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build

Reason: Invalid regular expression: /^�����n�w�,����P���xt��,�X�@m"A"�\^�����XR�9OjZ�ܮ8n�xr5⸮��"7���2��JT���}�\/1"c�Q!��RA� SsV=��D���V��6�
�}�#_�A0�i�0Z��l@�\+���zK��<[j�����ܻ�h�S�B�F
��
�����Ѧ�x��,�͠i�-!\^�\/Γ=��%\+g3���3���I
r�T�K��ŝ��u��VT9DB�\{��y�\^PU�Ƴ�\.t<�ø��\{t=��_�2��:"�}��Y�_XV&��1R�����3�\.B��g\)�N���8p��ƣ�����`\.�xr����\(��0ϧ�w[�F���
Ђ��(?=$|\/$)/: Range out of order in character class
```

However, there are no issues when running the project in the emulator. How can I resolve this issue?

i don't know what the original regex text looks like, the text that appears is really like that. I don't have any regex in my project, is it possible from a library?

**Edit**

I tried deleting the components one by one and building it. then after I delete
*/icon/burger.js* I found that EAS can build it.

**burger.js**

```
import * as React from "react"
import Svg, { Path } from "react-native-svg"

const Burger = () => (
  <Svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width={30}
    height={30}
    fill="white"
    className="bi bi-list"
    viewBox="0 0 16 16"

    stroke="white"
    
  >
    <Path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"
    />
  </Svg>
)
export default Burger
```

how can i solve? i need those symbols

Comment: Could it be due to some wrong charset settings? Looking at the error message with all these `�` chars makes me think of a mix between ANSI, UTF8, UTF16, BOM marker, etc. I don't know Expo, but just googled a bit and fell over [this regex issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1074). Just an idea... I hope you'll find what's the problem 

Comment: ^nw,Pxt,X@m"A"\^XR9OjZܮ8nxr5⸮"72JT}\/1"cQ!RA SsV=DV6}\#_A0i0Zl@\+zK<`[  <-- Unbalanced  '['`
jܻhSBFѦx,͠i-!\^\/Γ=%\+g33IrTKŝuVT9DB\{y\^PUƳ\.t<ø\{t=_2:"}Y_XV&1R3\.Bg\)N8pƣ\`\.xr\(0ϧw`[  <-- Unbalanced  '['`
FЂ(?=$|\/$)